# Dynamic array/matrix generating within formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

The following formula:

```
=TRIM(A1:A20)
```

would make no sense; you typically should decide a column, write `=TRIM(A1)` on first cell and copy until `=TRIM(A20)` ... *BUT* ... suppose you want/need to use it having the resulting array/matrix "dynamically" within a formula, for example in this way:

```
=VLOOKUP("FindMe",TRIM($A$1:$A$20),1,FALSE)
```

is it possible (without getting errors)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'd simply enter it as an **array formula***.

**Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you first hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and only then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets `{ }` around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you! Whoa, so simple...? (I'm almost ashamed...) And they're also available with Calc! (Although it seems you compulsorily need to click on the `"="` icon on formula bar before pressing SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER to make'em work...)
I already accepted your answer but please, one last thing, **can you provide your favorite link/reference on "array/matrix" matter**? Many thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. To be honest I've never been that impressed by any of the more popular sites' treatment of this topic. I would instead recommend that you search the various forums - including this one - for any appropriate material, taking the formulas provided and deconstructing them yourself via use of the in-built Evaluate Formula feature. Combining that with posting any questions you have when you get stuck and I for one will be happy to offer you full explanations. And you can of course also visit my site! http://excelxor.com/

Comment: Looking at your profile I realized with great delight you are a sort of spreadsheet-"array/matrix"-matters wizard! :-) This isn't Facebook but you have a new fan here! Going to upvote a lot of your other answers, thank you again!

Comment: P.S. nice site too, it seems really interesting. Keep up the good work! Thanks :-D

Comment: Always glad to have a new "fan"! Many thanks for your kind words - it's nice to know that some of my work is appreciated.

Comment: :-) i really mean it, keep up the good work, many, as me, will appreciate! Thanks, see you soon :-)